# Button border not applying properly due to padding values

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I've been trying to add border to a button through a border modifier, but it seems that whenever i change the padding to 7.dp (first image in attachment), it doesn't display the border right, but it appears alright when i apply 11.dp (second image in attachment)

Can anyone check what's the exact issue in below code!

```
Button(
   contentPadding = PaddingValues(
   start = 20.dp,
   end = 20.dp,
   top = if (size == ButtonBaseSize.normal) 11.dp else 7.dp,
       bottom = if (size == ButtonBaseSize.normal) 11.dp else 7.dp
   ),
   modifier = Modifier
      .wrapContentWidth()
      .border(width = 1.dp,
           color = if (theme == Theme.light) UiColor.gray_200 
             else UiColor.gray_700, shape = RoundedCornerShape(4.dp))
}{
   Text("")
}
```

It works fine when I set fix height of 34.dp to button, but i don't want to have fixed height as it should be decided but by the components inside the button content for more responsiveness

[Attachment for more insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTNKq.png)